# Generics where <t> Class library and MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, generics

I'm trying to learn how to use the 'where' in Generic, I seem to have it working but I not sure if how I have done it is the correct way.

Currently I have in a class library:

```
public class NewMembersViewModel
    {
        public NewMembersViewModel()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }

        [Display(Name = "Username")]
        [RemoteUsernameValidation("IsUserNameTaken", "Register", ErrorMessage = "Username already taken")]
        public string MemberUsername        { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string MemberPassword        { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        [RemoteEmailValidation("IsEmailTaken", "Register", ErrorMessage = "Email already in use")]
        public string MemberEmail           { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Mobile Number")]
        [RemoteMobileValidation("IsMobileTaken", "Register", ErrorMessage = "Mobile Number already in use")]
        public string MemberMobile          { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Forename")]
        public string MemberForename        { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Surname")]
        public string MemberSurname         { get; set; }

        public string Id                    { get; set; }
        public int VerificationCode         { get; set; }
    }
```

And

```
public static class SqlDatabaseMethods<T> where T : NewMembersViewModel
    {
        public static bool LoginUser(T member)
        {
            var p = member.MemberEmail;
            return true;
        }

        public static bool AddNewMember(T member)
        {
            var name = member.MemberForename;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Then in my MVC app I have:

```
bool name = SqlDatabaseMethods<NewMembersViewModel>.AddNewMember(model);

if (name)
{
    var test = "works";
}
```

This does work, can anyone tell me whether I doing it correctly, as all examples I have seen appear to be console apps

Comment: Do you have any classes that derive from `NewMembersViewModel` ? If not, there is only one concrete type and you don't need generics, because there will never be any `T` that is not a `NewMembersViewModel`.

Comment: Could you possibly explain more what you are trying to achieve with `SqlDatabaseMethods` - at the moment, the static methods just return true irrespective. Generics are most useful when you wish to DRY up the same code used across different types.

Comment: Hi @StuartLC i'm just learning how to use this type of functionality and as such, returning true was just a test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics make sense when you need have some functionality which is common across multiple classes. In this case `where` clause defines what the constraints of your generic type are. In such case generic methods help to re-use functionality.

In your case it doesn't seem that `SqlDatabaseMethods<T>` could be re-used more than once, as model `NewMembersViewModel` seems to be very specific and hardly re-usable elsewhere.

In your code you are using generics correctly, but in my opinion you don't need generics here at all. You could just as easily use the following code without the overhead of generics:

```
public static class SqlDatabaseMethods
{
    public static bool LoginUser(NewMembersViewModel member)
    {
        var p = member.MemberEmail;
        return true;
    }

    public static bool AddNewMember(NewMembersViewModel member)
    {
        var name = member.MemberForename;
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then call the method like this:

```
bool name = SqlDatabaseMethods.AddNewMember(model);
if (name)
{
    var test = "works";
}
```

Comment: Hi I'm learning how to use this type of functionality as I have never used it before. @dotnetom answer was very clear in the case that using 'where'  <T> is only really helpful when using the same functionality across many classes. But the fact that I have used it correctly in the MVC app was the main answer as that was the part of the code I was unsure about.